# Add plugins to the angular-cordova Angular plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, plugins

I've used angular for create my project, and it works perfectly.

Now i'm trying to wrapping it in a Cordova project, but I don't know how to use some Cordova plugin i need inside de Angular code...

how can I do? I'm trying to set the volume of the device (i'm interessed only in the android one) with the cordova-plugin-android-volume

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far. The API documentation is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-volume)

Comment: I've already installed it and I've clear how to use it in Cordova... but i need to use it inside an Angular .ts file.
I want to do this because my app is wrote in angular and wrapped inside cordova, so I can't use directly the cordova plugin inside the angular script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `cordova-plugin-android-volume` using

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/MCluck90/cordova-plugin-android-volume.git
```

Now, since you are using angular and Typescript, you need to declare `cordova` and `androidVolume` before you can use. See the code below using `declare` keyword

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var cordova: any;
declare var window: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  setVolume() {
    console.log(cordova);
    console.log(window.androidVolume);
  }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error: ```ERROR ReferenceError: cordova is not defined.```
if I try to print only the ```console.log(window.androidVolume);``` it returns me "undefined"

Comment: Did you include cordova.js in your index.html?

Comment: ok, now Cordova works... sorry. But ```console.log(window.androidVolume);``` gives me "undefined" and if I try to set the volume with ```window.androidVolume.setAll(100);``` it gives me the error "Cannot read property 'setAll' of undefined"